# Best way to handle device specific images in ios 7 and ios 7+

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, swift, ios8

Apps running in ios **4 and 4+** should now include two separate files for each image resource. One file provides a **standard-resolution** version of a given image, and the second provides a **high-resolution** version of the same image. The naming conventions for each pair of image files is as follows:

```
Standard:        <ImageName><device_modifier>.<filename_extension>

High Resolution: <ImageName>@2x<device_modifier>.<filename_extension>
```

***ex :***

```
name~iphone.png    
name@2x~iphone.png

name~ipad.png   
name@2x~ipad.png
```

This is the default naming convention introduced and defined it. [its documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreensInViews/SupportingHiResScreensInViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH15)!

**Intention of this story/question:**

i just want to know, what would be the best way to handle device specific images in project.

in less effort, while we have much more devices **(3.5 inch, 4 inch , 4.7 inch , 5.5 inch)** to consider in project.

Answer (score 0):

Use asset catalog. Image.xcassets in your project. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the iOS Interface Guidelines. Shows a table which suggests, only the 5.5 inch screen needs an asset change/name change:

[Guide here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1)

```
> Asset:
> 
> iPhone 6 Plus (@3x) 
>
> iPhone 6 and iPhone 5 (@2x)
>
>iPhone 4s (@2x) 
>
>iPad and iPad mini (Retina iPad and iPad Mini) (@2x) 
>
>iPad 2 and iPad mini (@1x)
```